# Fetching data return error code wrong version number

Tags: mysql, next.js, drizzle

Fetching data with Mysql return This Error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12442:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at globalThis.fetch (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_@babel+core@7.23.7_@opentelemetry+api@1.7.0_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/patch-fetch.js:216:16)
    at postJSON (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@planetscale+database@1.14.0/node_modules/@planetscale/database/dist/index.js:150:22)
    at Connection.execute (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@planetscale+database@1.14.0/node_modules/@planetscale/database/dist/index.js:102:23)
    at PlanetScalePreparedQuery.execute (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/drizzle-orm@0.29.3_@opentelemetry+api@1.7.0_@planetscale+database@1.14.0_@types+react@18.2.48_mysql2@3.7.1_react@18.2.0/node_modules/drizzle-orm/planetscale-serverless/session.js:43:26)
    at cachedCb (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_@babel+core@7.23.7_@opentelemetry+api@1.7.0_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/unstable-cache.js:143:28)
    at getUserStores (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/lib/fetchers/store.ts:50:16)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at StoresPage (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/(dashboard)/dashboard/stores/page.tsx:60:43) {
  cause: [Error: 0010D2DB01000000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:tls_validate_record_header:wrong version number:ssl/record/methods/tlsany_meth.c:81:
  ] {
    library: 'SSL routines',
    reason: 'wrong version number',
    code: 'ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER'
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me? I am Using NextJS MYSQL Database Mysql. I try it in localhost and Production in Verel ALson but the same error.

My code for example..

```
export async function getUserStores(input: { userId: string }) {
  try {
    return await cache(
      async () => {
        return db
          .select({
            id: stores.id,
            name: stores.name,
            description: stores.description,
            stripeAccountId: stores.stripeAccountId,
          })
          .from(stores)
          .leftJoin(products, eq(products.storeId, stores.id))
          .groupBy(stores.id)
          .orderBy(desc(stores.stripeAccountId), desc(sql<number>`count(*)`))
          .where(eq(stores.userId, input.userId))
      },
      ["user-stores"],
      {
        revalidate: 3600,
        tags: ["user-stores"],
      }
    )()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return []
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a connection error. Please provide how you set it up. However, based on the error message, it probably is MySQL using an SSL version that is no longer supported in node.

Comment: Are you really using drizzle? But more likely, which MySQL version? I'd grab a wireshark capture of the connection attempt and look and the client/server hello message and see what each other are setting the as the TLS version to be. Or set a minium version like [this](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/2394)

Answer (score 0):

For drizzle mysql and this error- there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-app/issues/1587).

In short, they propose to use host, username and password instead of connection url

```js
import * as schema from "./schema";

import { connect } from "@planetscale/database";
import { drizzle } from "drizzle-orm/planetscale-serverless";

// create the connection
const connection = connect({
  host: env.DATABASE_HOST,
  username: env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  password: env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
});

export const db = drizzle(connection, { schema });
```